# How to use Ember Adapter

Tags: ember.js, adapter

Why the 'Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();' replace to '
  Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: "todos-emberjs"
  });
' can be achieved local stores?

what's the meaning of 'namespace: "todos-emberjs"'?

There are how much kinds of adapters? And I should how to use them? How to define an adapter?

Answer (score 2):

[(Check out the picture here to see where ADAPTER component fits in)](http://emberjs.com/images/guides/models/finding-unloaded-record-step1-diagram.png)

I just went through EmberJS tutorial recently and from what I understood:

**1)What are EmberJS adapters?**
The adapters are objects that take care of communication between your application and a server. Whenever your application asks the store for a record that it doesn't have cached, it will ask the adapter for it. If you change a record and save it, the store will hand the record to the adapter to send the appropriate data to your server and confirm that the save was successful.

**2)What types of EmberJS adapters are available?**
Right now I am only aware of **DS.RESTAdapter** which is used by default by the store (it communicates with an HTTP server by transmitting JSON via XHR), **DS.FixtureAdapter**(something like in-memory storage which is not persistent) and **DS.LSAdapter**(something like local-storage which is persistent).

**3)Why LSAdapter instead of FixtureAdapter in Todos tutorial?**
FixtureAdapter stores data in-memory and thus whenever you refresh your page, the data gets reassigned to initial values. But LSAdapter is available on github which uses persistent storage to store and retrieve data, hence enabling you to retain all the changes even after you refresh your page.

**4)Why namespace: "todos-emberjs"?**
If your JSON API lives somewhere other than on the host root, you can set a prefix that will be added to all requests. For example, if your JSON APIs are available at **/todo-emberjs/** you would want it to be used as a prefix to all the URLs that you are going to call. In that case, set namespace property to **todo-emberjs**.

(Hope it helps, loving EmberJS btw !)